# can rubymine 4.5.4 run ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Does anyone know if rubymine 4.5.4 has support for ruby 2.0?  I see it in the patch notes for rubymine 5.0.2 but our corporate license doesn't cover the upgrade to rubymine 5.0.2.  I don't want to download ruby 2.0 to test it if I don't have to (risk of screwing up the test suite) but I want to make sure I bring this to someone's attention before testers start upgrading ruby and cannot run it on our IDE.

Comment: Are you unable to use RVM to sandbox Ruby 2.0?  RubyMine knows how to work with RVM, so that should give you a safe enough environment to try the two together.

I would not be optimistic, though.  Probably safest to tell the testers to keep their mitts off of 2.0 unless and until the company can spring for a new license.